# Why this is showing wrong answer in C

Tags: c

```
long long int x;
 x=958657431*100;
```

for this

i am getting answer =1376462588

why it is happening can anyone explain whereas I am getting correct answer when I am doing x=x*100; in next line

Comment: The `958657431` should be `958657431ll` or `958657431LL`. MSVC compiler warns *integral constant overflow*.

Comment: The multiplication is done as an `int` not `long long int`

Comment: the answer is as good as possible, but your question to the compiler is wrong ^^

Comment: Aside: although both operands fit a 32-bit `int` the product does not - it is the **compiler** doing the multiplication, because it can, and that is why the warning was given. If the operands were two variables, there would be no compiler warning, just a run-time overflow.

Comment: Learn about signed integer overflow, as it is a series bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is obvious if you look at your compiler warnings.

```
/tmp$ gcc main.c 
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:16: warning: integer overflow in expression of type ‘int’ results in ‘1376462588’ [-Woverflow]
     x=958657431*100;
                ^
```

When you're doing an assignment on the form `x = expr` the evaluation of `expr` is completely unaware of the type of `x`. A multiplication of two `int` will always yield a result with the type `int`, even if it overflows.

One solution is to add a type suffix like this:

```
x = 958657431LL * 100;
```

or use a cast

```
x = (long long)958657431 * 100;
```

Note:

Overflowing a *signed* variable results in *undefined behavior* which means that ANYTHING may happen, including the program working as it should.

Comment: then why  x=9586574315*10; this is running correctly

Comment: @ExpectationsvsReality I get the same warning for that.

Comment: That is still bigger than 2^31. and so is `9586574315` in the first place.

Comment: @ExpectationsvsReality To clarify a bit. It's still UB, and asking why code with UB works is pointless, because you have no *guarantee* that it will work. If it does you're just lucky (or unlucky, depending on how you see it)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `958657431*100` is evaluated as an `int`, not as a `long long int`.

It seems that on your platform, an `int` cannot hold the value `95865743100`. Hence you get something else.

Use

```
x = 958657431LL * 100;
```

to get the multiplication to be done on `long long int` instead of `int`.

Comment: what if I want to use it in variable

Comment: @ExpectationsvsReality, please elaborate.

Comment: actually code was something like this ans=n%max*n%max; ans=ans%max this is not working because I am getting 958657431 value while doing ans%max

Comment: Maybe you should start a new question posting a new minimal example that matches your actual code better.

Comment: I cant ask question anymore

Comment: @ExpectationsvsReality, since you are expecting to encounter numbers that cannot be held in an `int`, use `long long int` for `max` as well `n`. Then you can bypass the problem altogether.